# Search record in ACCESS DATABASE using c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, c#-2.0

i am trying to find the records based on the user input in msaccess database.
below is the code

```
string strProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Employees.mdb";
string strSql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_employees where description like '" + txtsearch.Text.ToString() + "*'";

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strProvider);
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, con);
con.Open();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
int columnCount = dr.FieldCount;
```

When i ran the same query in my SQLView of msaccess i am getting records but when i ran it in VS i am not getting any records.

Comment: Is there a difference somehow between what you put in the `LIKE` in your test versus what you are getting from `txtsearch.Text.ToString()`?

Comment: No there are no difference

Comment: What is `dr.FieldCount` returning?

Comment: Put a break point in your `OleDbConnection...` line and when you get there, check value of your `strSql`. And tell us what it writes..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your matching should be changed:

```
String strSql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_employees WHERE description LIKE '" + txtsearch.Text.ToString() + "%'";

//Replaced * with %
```

Comment: @SonerGönül This is going to depend upon the underlying ANSI query mode.  In "SQL compatibility mode" the `%` is the required wildcard, and that is likely what's happening here.  Access will allow the `*` and perhaps both, but the OleDb query will reject the `*`.  In fact, I believe that OleDb always uses the compatibility mode (ANSI-92 Query Mode).